# C++ fread: unsigned char and short mixture

Tags: c++, sizeof, fread

I have a sample code here:

```
    unsigned char *m_fbytes;
    m_fbytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(m_iByteLen1FrameDecoded*sizeof(short));

    int err;
    err = fread(m_fbytes, sizeof(short), 960, fin);
    curr_read = err;
    for(int i=0;i<curr_read;i++)
    {
        opus_int32 s;
        s=m_fbytes[2*i+1]<<8|m_fbytes[2*i];
        s=((s&0xFFFF)^0x8000)-0x8000;
        m_in[i]=s;
    }

    int iLen = encode(m_enc, m_in, m_iByteLen1FrameDecoded, m_data, m_max_payload_bytes);
```

I don't understand this line:

```
err = fread(m_fbytes, sizeof(short), 960, fin);
```

The authors of this code read some bytes (aka unsigned char), but they pass sizeof(short).

Why do they use "sizeof(short)"?

Comment: The input is read in chunks of `sizeof (short)` bytes. Why should be obvious from the file format. Or am I misunderstanding what your question is?

Comment: I want to say they are incorrect, and they should be saying sizeof(char), but just unsure enough that I'm just going to add this comment

Comment: @greedybuddha Why should that be incorrect? It's a buffer for some `short`s, typed as an array of `unsigned char`s.

Comment: i'm seeing an array of char, being read in with the size of short

Comment: If you look at the rest of the code, they use a char pointer because they address the data a char at a time.  Sure, you could tell fread to read 1920 chars instead of 960 shorts, but it's the same amount of data either way.

Comment: @greedybuddha As I said. It's a buffer for at least 960 `short`s. For ease of per-byte manipulation, it's typed as an array of `unsigned char`. That's legal. And as this is actually C code and not really C++, it's not even too surprising.

Comment: It just seems to me this is programmers trying to be tricky, which works fine until someone changes the ratio of the size between shorts and chars.  Why even open yourself up to this possibility?

Comment: Notice that memory was allocated for shorts too. fread(m_fbytes, sizeof(short), 960, fin) - here sizeof(short) is a size of element, 960 is count of elements => reads 960 shorts from file. Nothing wrong here

Comment: *forehead.  Yeah thanks kotlomoy, that's what I was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code contains a couple of tacit assumptions that make it unnecessarily fragile. The way the read bytes are used

```
s=m_fbytes[2*i+1]<<8|m_fbytes[2*i];
s=((s&0xFFFF)^0x8000)-0x8000;
```

the assumptions are

- `CHAR_BIT == 8`; that's a pretty safe assumption nowadays, unless one deals with exotic hardware, but it's not guaranteed.
- `sizeof(short) == 2`; that's also very likely to be true, but not guaranteed either.

The way the read bytes are used, each adjacent pair of them make up one unit in the final result (and thus using `2` instead of `sizeof(short)` would be more robust, if `sizeof(short) > 2`, it would use only part of the read data [if `sizeof(short) == 1`, `CHAR_BIT` must be at least 16, in that case stuff will break in a different way]).

The `size` parameter to `fread` is used to specify how many bytes make up one unit, so that no partial units are read, and the buffer contains `err` complete units.

Comment: The `0xFFFF` mask would be unnecessary under those assumptions.

Comment: Not if `int` is 16 bits wide. Then you can get sign-extension if the most significant bit of `m_fbytes[2*i+1]` is set - but then you already have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As You can see, this code make some encoding/decoding. Then it allocates a block in the memory, and casts is to `unsigned char`. This cast's reason is that You want to use the first and the second byte of the readed values.

With reading short numbers

- You will know how the number of the succesful reads.
- You can easily handle special cases like if the input contains odd number of characters